XML to CSV for child nodes
With below XSLT code able to convert from XML to CSV with enclosed quotes, but the child node (Details) is appearing in the same line.
Update: As mentioned in the forum I have updated the question with expected output.
XML Input
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Root>
  <Records>
    <TrRecords>
      <RecordID>0123</RecordID>
      <SequnceNumber>00001</SequnceNumber>
      <TNumber>00001</TNumber>
      <System>01</System>
      <Amount>4956.00</Amount>
     <Reference>T</Reference>
     <Account>89768</Account>
     <Name>bdi</Name>
    <Other2/>
    <Other3/>
    <Details>
   <RecordID>1234</RecordID>
  <SequnceNumber>00001</SequnceNumber>
   <TNumber>00001</TNumber>
  <Number>TI</Number>
<InvoiceDate>2024-05-05</InvoiceDate>
 <InvoiceDescription/>
 <InvoiceAmount>10.00</InvoiceAmount>
 </Details>
  <Details>
   <RecordID>1234</RecordID>
  <SequnceNumber>00002</SequnceNumber>
   <TNumber>00001</TNumber>
  <Number>TI3</Number>
<InvoiceDate>2024-05-05</InvoiceDate>
 <InvoiceDescription/>
 <InvoiceAmount>10.00</InvoiceAmount>
 </Details>
</TrRecords>
 <TrRecords>
 <RecordID>0123</RecordID>
 <SequnceNumber>00001</SequnceNumber>
 <TNumber>00002</TNumber>
 <System>01</System>
 <Amount>523.00</Amount>
 <Reference>TI</Reference>
 <Account>18907</Account>
<Name>elci</Name>
 <Other2/>
 <Other3/>
 <Details>
 <RecordID>1234</RecordID>
<SequnceNumber>00001</SequnceNumber>
 <TNumber>00001</TNumber>
  <Number>TIR</Number>
 <InvoiceDate>2024-08-17</InvoiceDate>
 <InvoiceDescription/>
 <InvoiceAmount>5245.00</InvoiceAmount>
   </Details>
  </TrRecords>
   <TrRecords>
    <RecordID>0123</RecordID>
   <Number>00001</Number>
   <TNumber>00003</TNumber>
    <System>01</System>
   <Amount>1180.00</Amount>
  <Reference>EMI</Reference>
<AccountNo>0936201002941</AccountNo>
   <Other2/>
    <Other3/>
 <Details>
  <RecordID>1234</RecordID>
  <SequnceNumber>00001</SequnceNumber>
   <TNumber>00001</TNumber>
   <Number>Tac</Number>
   <InvoiceDate>2024-08-17</InvoiceDate>
   <InvoiceDescription/>
    <InvoiceAmount>1180.00</InvoiceAmount>
     </Details>
  </TrRecords>
   </Records>
   </Root>

XSLT code
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
  <xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />
  <xsl:param name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
   <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />
  <xsl:template match="/Root">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Records/TrRecords" />
   </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="TrRecords">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
   <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
    <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
    </xsl:if>
  <xsl:for-each select="Details">
  <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
  <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*">
<!-- remove normalize-space()  --> 
   <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(), $quote)" />
  <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
  <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
   </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()" />
  </xsl:stylesheet>

Expected output
"0123","00001","00001","01","4956.00","T","89768","bdi","",""
"1234","00001","00001","TI","2024-05-05","","10.00"
"1234","00002","00001","TI3","2024-05-05","","10.00"
"0123","00001","00002","01","523.00","TI","18907","elci","",""
"1234","00001","00001","TIR","2024-08-17","","5245.00"
"0123","00001","00003","01","1180.00","EMI","0936201002941","",""
"1234","00001","00001","Tac","2024-08-17","","1180.00"

In each line from 1234 the values should come in new line with enclosed quotes. could you please help me with this.
Regards,
Janardhan

Please edit your question and show the exact output you want to get.

@michael.hor257k I have updated the question with expected output.

(modified)
Try something like:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
<xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />
<xsl:param name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
<xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />
   
<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Records/TrRecords" />
</xsl:template>
   
<xsl:template match="TrRecords">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="* except Details"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Details"/>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
 
<xsl:template match="Details">
    <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
 
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(), $quote)" />
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
   
</xsl:stylesheet>

Demo here.
Note that this assumes none of the values passed to the output contains a quote.

I have tried with above code but under TrRecrods if multiple details segments are in XML then it is coming in single line. Below is the example.
"1234","00001","00001","TI","2024-05-05","","10.00","1234","00003","00001","TI3","2024-05-05","","10.00"

There weren't multiple Details in your original question. I have modified my answer, but ...

I have tried with the updated code and now Details records are populating in a same line TrRecords. Detail records should be in new line.
"0123","00001","00001","01","4956.00","T","89768","bdi","","","1234 00001 00001 TI 2024-05-05 10.00","1234 00002 00001 TI3 2024-05-05 10.00"
"0123","00001","00002","01","523.00","TI","18907","elci","","","1234 00001 00001 TIR 2024-08-17 5245.00"
"0123","00001","00003","01","1180.00","EMI","0936201002941","","","1234 00001 00001 Tac 2024-08-17 1180.00"

That is not the result I get (see the link in my answer).

Problem with my application. It seems now it is working fine. Thank you very much for your help!

The main problem you have is that in the template which matches TrRecords, you call apply-templates to process all the child elements of the TrRecords, which includes the Details elements, but then later you explicitly iterate over those Details elements again.
Here's a stylesheet with 4 templates:

one which matches the root, and applies templates to the TrRecords,
one which matches the TrRecords elements and applies templates to their child elements
one which matches a Details elements and applies templates to its child elements (NB this ensures that a Details element found inside a TrRecords element is treated as a row of output, containing elements which are columns, rather than being treated like a column itself)
one which matches any other element and outputs it as a quoted string

NB the TrRecords template adds a line break after processing the child elements, while the Details template adds a line break before processing its child elements.
Also note that the $delim string is inserted after rendering a column value only if there are following siblings other than Details elements.
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
   <xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />
   <xsl:param name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
   <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />
   
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Records/TrRecords" />
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="TrRecords">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Details">
      <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, ., $quote)" />
      <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[not(self::Details)]">
         <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Personally, though, if I had an XSLT 2 interpreter available, I'd be inclined to write this differently, with just one template and a more elaborate XPath expression:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
   <xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />
   <xsl:param name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
   <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />
   
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of separator="{$break}" select="
        for $row in 
          (Root/Records/TrRecords | Root/Records/TrRecords/Details)
        return
          string-join(
            for $col in $row/*[not(self::Details)] return concat($quote, $col, $quote),
            $delim
          )
      "/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

